# Show layer/div with links over an image on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layer

We are trying to mimic something like on [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/us/en/) - see image box (Lets build a smarter planet box) which when mover overs, shows a layer with links.

Any help/reference highly appreciated.

Thanks!
K

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a javascript tooltip plugin.
Try google "jquery tooltip plugin".

A good plugin is the [flowplayer tooltip plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/slide.html) ([howto](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html), [download](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html)). You can do custom html in the tooltip box.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common effect. They have a scroll pane following with hidden, absolutely positioned container `.ibm-expand-overlay`. They both are wrapped in relatively positioned `div`. Effect is triggered on `mouseenter` of pane child, in their case `.ibm-columns`

```
$('.ibm-columns').mouseenter( function() {

  //some positioning logic is needed here
  //probably $('.ibm-expand-overlay').css('left', $(this).index() * childWidth ) is sufficient enought

  $('.ibm-expand-overlay').fadeIn();
} );

$('.ibm-expand-overlay').mouseleave( function() { $(this).fadeOut(); } ); //to hide on mouseleave
```